# How do i approach translating something i can't define nor understand: 「まっかせなさーい」

Tags: translation

> まっかせなさーい

Kaname Chidori keeps coming with these outrageous lines that I struggle to even compartmentalize.

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like a funky 任せなさい

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**任せなさい >>> It means "Just leave it to me !" or "You can count on me !"**

I have a feeling that this character felt very confident about his/her own skill, and volunteered to do something.

Hope this helps you.